# Why can the remotecommand not be called and the poll be stopped by javascript in second tab?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am developing a loadtest-page. One loadtest-page is working well in a browser tab, but if two loadtest-page runs in parallel in each own browser tab, then the second loadtest-page is not working after finishing of the loadtest-page.

The problem at second page is, if the progress reaches 100%, then the remotecommand is not called and the poll is not stopped by a javascript function checkProgress. At first page it is working well. If both progress take more than 30 minutes then the problem at second page occurs.

Where is the problem?

Here code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <p:poll widgetVar="poll-load-current-metrics" listener="#{loadTestProgress.loadCurrentMetrics}" global="false"
            interval="3" autoStart="false" update="progressbar-loadtest-webservice checkProgress" process="@this"
            oncomplete="checkProgress();"/>
    <p:progressBar id="progressbar-loadtest-webservice" widgetVar="progress-loadtest-webservice"
                   value="#{loadTestProgress.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" global="false">
    </p:progressBar>
    <br/>
    <p:outputPanel id="panel-current-statistics" autoUpdate="true">
.....
    </p:outputPanel>
    <h:panelGroup id="checkProgress">
        <h:outputScript>
            function checkProgress() {
            console.debug("checking progress");
            if('#{loadTestProgress.progress}' == 100) {
            console.debug("Progress == 100");
            console.debug('stopping poll');
            PF('poll-load-current-metrics').stop();
            remoteProgressClose();
            }
            }
        </h:outputScript>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:remoteCommand process="@this"
                     oncomplete="console.debug('starting');PF('poll-load-current-metrics').start();"
                     autoRun="true" rendered="#{running}" global="false"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="remoteProgressClose" actionListener="#{loadTestProgress.close}"
                     process="@this"
                     update="#{updateArea}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: The title of your Q sort of conflicts with the first line. Title says it is not working, first sentence says it does. The major issue being 'two tabs' which you do not mention in the title. Secondly, why do you have 'autoStart' on the poll set to false and then use a remoteCommand with `autoRun="true"` (without calling anything on the server or updating anything in the client) to start it? Thirdly, what did you debug? Did you analyse request/responses etc?

Comment: Btw, what is the scope of `loadTestProgress`? This is **very** relevant and missing in the question.

Comment: you are right with title. I will correct it. The loadtestProgress is include-page and a part of loadtest-page. If the loadtestProgress is updated by another jsf-component, then the first remotecommand runs automatically if loadtest is running. I tried poll with 'autoRun="true"' and 'rendered="#{running}', but it is not working.

Comment: There are no error message in debug. Only all correct output --> 'Progress == 100', 'stopping poll' I see in debug that the javascript functions PF().stop() and remoteProgressClose() are not called in second tab.

Comment: 'loadTestProgress' bean is in 'viewScope'